# Getting rid of 'unused variables warnings' in Python

Tags: python, loops

I have a somewhat whacky loop that works very well to get nested values from a dict.

```
for k, v in bdict.items():
        for k1, v1 in v.items():
            for k2, v2 in v1.items():
                for k3, v3 in v2.items():
                    blindex += v3
```

As you can tell, I don't actually want the keys, and VS Code keeps giving me annoying warnings that I have unused variables. Can I do anything to mute these, or maybe a better way to get this data in general?

Comment: If you don't want the keys, why are you looping over `.items()`?  Loop over `.values()` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

instead of `v.items` use `v.values` if you don't care about what the keys are:

```
for v in bdict.values():
    for v1 in v.values():
        for v2 in v1.values():
            for v3 in v2.values():
                blindex+=v3
```

Answer (score 2):

Replacing the values that you don't care about to `_` should work. So:

```
for _, v in bdict.items():
        for _, v1 in v.items():
            for _, v2 in v1.items():
                for _, v3 in v2.items():
                    blindex += v3
```

However, you might want to look into `.values()`, so `bdict.values()` for example.

Answer (score 2):

you can replace all the variables you aren't using with a single underscore "_"

```
for _, v in bdict.items():
        for _, v1 in v.items():
            for _, v2 in v1.items():
                for _, v3 in v2.items():
                    blindex += v3
```

this tells python you're not interested in in the keys. Another way is using values method instead of items method.

```
for v in bdict.values():
        for v1 in v.values():
            for v2 in v1.values():
                for v3 in v2.values():
                    blindex += v3
```

Any way I should warn you: this code seems fragile

Comment: Can you explain a bit what makes it fragile? I would appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

If you dont want the keys and only interested in the values then just call `values()` instead of `items()`

```py
for v in bdict.values():
        for v1 in v.values():
            for v2 in v1.values():
                for v3 in v2.values():
                    blindex += v3
```

Comment: just at the same time xD